# Why does gradle tries to resolve depdencyversion with a space as last character?

Tags: gradle

I am a little bit curios why gradle behave the way it does and how to avoid it. We configure the version of our dependencies in `gradle.properties`. For example:

`batikVersion                      = 1.8`

then we use this defined version in `build.gradle` the following ways:
`compile group: "org.apache.xmlgraphics", name: "batik-transcoder", version: "${batikVersion}"`

Everything works fine until the moment we insert a space as the last character for batikVersion. So it becomes:
"batikVersion                      = 1.8 "

Now gradle says it can't find the dependency because there ist no "1.8 ". Why is the space not removed for resolving dependencies and how can we avoid such mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gradle.properties` file is a normal Java properties file. When Java reads a property file, it will ignore leading spaces but not trailing spaces. This is probably because sometimes you may want to actually provide a string with spaces at the end of it (though I never needed that).

You could argue that Gradle could perform a `.trim()` to the values you provide to the dependency. If you think it is valuable, you could create a feature request on the Gradle issue list. But otherwise, the way to avoid it is just to stop making typos in your properties files :)

Comment: So I made my first gradle feature request - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11603 because I will continue to make typos in my properties file :-P